# What conditions must be met in order to upload .zip file to a multisite Wordpress installation?

Tags: hooks, uploads, wp-config

I cannot upload .zip files to my Wordpress network, despite [making IMHO everything](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/wordpress/how-to-fix-the-sorry-this-file-type-is-not-permitted-for-security-reasons-error-in-wordpress) that is needed. I am still hit by this irritating error.

[image]

Details:

1. [I am a super-admin](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45818) in my network.
2. The `ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS` flag [is set to `true`](https://onezeronull.com/2021/05/12/file-upload-blocked-despite-allow_unfiltered_uploads-set-to-true/#enable-upload-of-all-files)
3. [Custom hook](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/387876/17323) of `$existing_mimes['zip'] = 'application/zip';` is added
4. Uploading .zip files is allowed in my network:

[image]

Here is entire code of my hook:

```
function so_387865_custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes ) {
    $existing_mimes['epub'] = 'application/epub+zip';
    $existing_mimes['mobi'] = 'application/x-mobipocket-ebook';
    $existing_mimes['zip'] = 'application/zip';
 
    return $existing_mimes;
}
 
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'so_387865_custom_upload_mimes');
```

I thought that maybe there's something wrong with the hook, so I have installed the [*Enhanced Media Library* extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-media-library/) (as suggested in [here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/wordpress/how-to-fix-the-sorry-this-file-type-is-not-permitted-for-security-reasons-error-in-wordpress)). All for nothing, as it clearly shows that this MIME type is added:

[image]

**What [else](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/wordpress/how-to-fix-the-sorry-this-file-type-is-not-permitted-for-security-reasons-error-in-wordpress)** should I do in order to be able to upload .zip files? I am seriously lost!

**EDIT**: *As suggested [in here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/387876/17323), this custom hook is added directly (`custom_hooks.php` file in `wp-content/mu-plugins/` folder). While most guides in the net says about adding custom mimes directly in the theme's code. Maybe this is a problem?*

Comment: I know I've had issues in the past using a MIME type different from the one WordPress was expecting. But `application/zip` looks pretty standard to my eye. Have you tried giving your `add_filter()` call a higher priority (ie, change it to `add_filter('upload_mimes', 'so_387865_custom_upload_mimes', 20 );`)?

Comment: As for your suggestion, either I missing something or you made it exactly opposite. [Codex says](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/): "_Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution_". So I should rather go with `1` not `20` in order to give in higher priority. Anyway, nothing helped, neither `20` nor `1`. But... As for my question. It seems it is off-topic, because this clearly is some bug in Gutenberg's File block type. I can upload these files without any problems into my _Media_ section of the very same files. Only direct upload to File block fails.

Comment: It's a bit confusing. I think of the number as a *weight*: a higher number is heavier, and therefore later. The higher the number, the later the execution; if a function at priority `1` returns `foo` and one at priority `100` returns `bar`, then WP will receive the later one and it'll be `bar`.

Comment: There is an open issue for that: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40175

Comment: @funkysoul Yeap, just came here to report this as well.

Answer (score 4):

The issue has nothing to do with the source code of a theme or plugin or with the configuration of Wordpress. It is:

- a [6+ months old bug in File block in Gutenberg](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/23510) that narrows down to
- a [4+ years old bug in core Wordpress](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40175).

No solution exists for the moment, except for uploading files via *Media* section of Wordpress Dasboard. As file upload through that way are 100% working without any problems.